# Cart functionality in Magento from scratch

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm fairly new to Magento and am setting up a new theme from scratch. I'm not using any of the standard Magento JS files until now and I've included jQuery and a js file for custom scripts.

Now I'm looking into recreating the Add To Cart functionality but standard wise this seems to call some js function which I do not have declared now (lacking the Magento JS files). I'd like to set it up on my own with an ordinary form submit.

Can anyone give me an example of how to execute the Add To Cart command for the product I'm currently viewing? Without the necessity of standard Magento JS files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Magento do for add to cart is it calls `productAddToCartForm.submit` function of javascript to validate all required field and if true then it submit product form.

So you can call your javascript method for form submit and add to cart.

Add to cart button comes from this file, so you can change onclick event here.

```
app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\view\addtocart.phtml
```